# How do I change App name in AppInfo in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I've changed the App name in all places and compiles ok; even under the icon to open the App the name is ok but in AppInfo under the App logo there's the old name.

How do I change that?

Comment: Can you share the Application tag on your AndroidManifest.xml file? I just want to check that you also updated the name in `android:label`

Comment: @FMontano Yes, I did it, I changed all the files that contained the old name with the new one. I used a tool to search that text in all the project files and even changed some folder names with the new name too. I don't understand where the virtual phone takes that name.

Comment: @FMontano  In my phone works fine. I don't understand.